# Add hyperlink in Dataframe cell

Tags: python, pandas

df =

```
            A     B   
            a  b  a  b
2016-11-21  2  1  3  0
2016-11-22  3  4  1  0
2016-11-23  5  2  1  6
2016-11-24  6  3  1  5
2016-11-25  6  3  0  2
```

I want to make these dates as hyperlink so that when I click on that it redirect me to a webpage. 
PS: URL would be different for each dates.

Comment: It seems hyperlink is added as a separate column on the link you provided. I do not want to add a separate  column for hyperlink. Instead want to make date as hyperlink itself (point to some url)

Comment: Dates are indexes here.